# Create a DataFrame in Pandas using an index from an existing TimeSerie and a column form another TimeSerie

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I want to create a DataFrame or TimeSerie using an index of an existing TimeSerie and the values from another TimeSerie with different time indices. The TimeSeries look like;

```
 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
DT
2018-01-02    172.3000
2018-01-03    174.5500
2018-01-04    173.4700
2018-01-05    175.3700
2018-01-08    175.6100
2018-01-09    175.0600
2018-01-10    174.3000
2018-01-11    175.4886
2018-01-12    177.3600
2018-01-16    179.3900
2018-01-17    179.2500
2018-01-18    180.1000
...
```

and

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
DT
2018-01-02        NaN
2018-01-09    175.610
2018-01-16    177.360
2018-01-23    180.100
...
```

I want to use the index from the first TS and fill it with the values with appropriate index form the second TS. Like;

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
DT
2018-01-02   NaN
2018-01-03   NaN
2018-01-04   NaN
2018-01-05   NaN
2018-01-08   NaN
2018-01-09   175.610
2018-01-10   NaN
2018-01-11   NaN
2018-01-12   NaN
2018-01-16   177.360
2018-01-17   NaN
2018-01-18   NaN
...
```

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use [`Series.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
new_s = s2.reindex(s1.index)

#2018-01-02       NaN
#2018-01-03       NaN
#2018-01-04       NaN
#2018-01-05       NaN
#2018-01-08       NaN
#2018-01-09    175.61
#2018-01-10       NaN
#2018-01-11       NaN
#2018-01-12       NaN
#2018-01-16    177.36
#2018-01-17       NaN
#2018-01-18       NaN
#Name: s2, dtype: float64
```

Comment: It works fine for the problem I described, thx! Is it also possible to get a value in the newly created TS if there is an row for some index in s2, but not in s1? This for the first date in s1 that comes after the date in s2.

Answer (score 0):

convert your series data structure into a Data frame Data structure then use the following line :
pd.merge(TS1,TS2,left_index=True,right_index=True,how='left').iloc[:,-1]

Comment: to convert from time-series to data-frame you can use :
series.to_frame()